# Finding the modal hue of an image

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of my first python project, I needed to know what the dominant hue of an image was.

I started with finding the modal hue of the image, but the results seemed really odd in images with pale/dark backgrounds. This lead me to applying a threshold to both the saturation and value channels of a HSV image, so as to ignore pale and dark colours before finding the mode of the remaining hues.

I have tried to improve the speed by using numpy instead of a list comprehension, however this ended up being just over twice as slow.

I would appreciate any improvements, especially towards performance, but also to making it more pythonic.

```py
from PIL import Image
from scipy import stats

def get_hue(image_path):
    """
    Returns the modal hue of the image 0-360 after applying a saturation and value threshold of 30%
    If there are no pixels that pass the threshold, the value threshold is dropped down to 10%
    """
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("HSV")
    colours = image.getdata()
    s_threshold = 0.3*255
    v_threshold = 0.1*255
    filtered_colors = [x[0] for x in colours if x[1]> s_threshold and x[2] > s_threshold]
    if not filtered_colors:
        filtered_colors = [x[0] for x in colours if x[1] > s_threshold and x[2] > v_threshold]
    return ((stats.mode(filtered_colors).mode[0]/255)*360)//1
```

The Numpy Version

```py
from PIL import Image
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def get_hue_numpy(image_path):
    """
    Returns the modal hue of the image 0-360 after applying a saturation and value threshold of 30%
    If there are no pixels that pass the threshold, the value threshold is dropped down to 10%
    """
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("HSV")
    s_threshold = 0.3*255
    v_threshold = 0.1*255
    colours = np.array(image.getdata())
    filtered_colors = colours[(colours[:,1] > s_threshold) & (colours[:,2] > s_threshold)][:,0]
    if not filtered_colors.any():
        filtered_colors = colours[(colours[:,1] > s_threshold) & (colours[:,2] > v_threshold)][:,0]    
    return ((stats.mode(filtered_colors).mode[0]/255)*360)//1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to improve the speed by using numpy instead of a list comprehension

Your current solution uses two list comprehensions, and you haven't shown your Numpy attempt. I'll demonstrate what I consider to be idiomatic Numpy, which is indeed faster.

Other points:

Add PEP484 type hints.

I don't see why you should effectively floor (though in an awkward way, with `//1`). Why not just return the float? If the caller doesn't like it, they can `round()`.

### Suggested

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy import stats


def get_hue(image_path: str) -> float:
    """
    Returns the modal hue of the image 0-360 after applying a saturation and value threshold of 30%
    If there are no pixels that pass the threshold, the value threshold is dropped down to 10%
    """
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("HSV")
    colours = np.array(image)

    def val_predicate(val):
        return colours[..., 2] > val*255

    val_passes = val_predicate(0.3)
    if not np.any(val_passes):
        val_passes = val_predicate(0.1)

    sat_passes = colours[..., 1] > 0.3*255
    filtered_hue = colours[np.bitwise_and(sat_passes, val_passes), 0]
    mode, count = stats.mode(filtered_hue)
    return mode / 255 * 360
```

### Timing

For a 1920x1080 914KiB JPG image, the old list comprehension method completes in 351 ms and the new one in 111 ms.

### Profiling

I encourage you to learn `cProfile`. Your old numpy attempt shows, at the top,

```
         14016 function calls (13519 primitive calls) in 0.670 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.572    0.286    0.572    0.286 {built-in method numpy.array}
```

This shows that it's a problem in the array construction itself. Drop your `getdata()` and the problem goes away.

Comment: My attempt at using numpy was basically replacing the list comprehensions with `colours[(colours[:,1] > s_threshold) & (colours[:,2] > s_threshold)][:,0]` and passing the result of `image.getdata()` to `np.array` which took runtime from 92ms to around 257ms for a 640x640 JPG image. Using your version it is down to 15ms. Thank you so much! Would you mind adding an explantion as to why what I was doing with numpy was so much worse?

Comment: Difficult to say unless you show your entire Numpy attempt in the question.

Comment: Just added the numpy version I previously tried to the question

Comment: Updated: most of the problem is in how you load the array